# how to generate a random matrix with Orthogonalized rows using Gram-Schmidt algorithm in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, orthogonal

I want to generate a M*N matrix (M is not equal to N) with following constraints in MATLAB:

Step 1. Set each entry of the matrix to an i.i.d. N(0,1) value.

Step 2. Orthogonalize the M rows of the matrix using the Gram-Schmidt algorithm.

Step 3. Normalize the rows of the matrix to unit length.

I do not know how to implement second step of above.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process#Example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look at [`orth`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/orth.html):

```
A = randn( m, n );  % random iid ~N(0,1)
oA = orth( A.' ).'; % orthogonal rows
nA = bsxfun( @rdivide, oA, sqrt( sum( oA.^2, 2 ) ) ); % normalize to unit length
```

Comment: Thank @Shai, But there is no difference between oA and nA.

Comment: `oA` is already normalized - this is the output of `orth`. Therefore, the third stage is redundant I only put it for methodical reasons. You may ignore it.

Comment: Please take a look at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/48300 Notice `qr(A) ~= orth(A)`. Here http://www.math.purdue.edu/~wang838/teaching/GramSchmidt.pdf implements a G-S algo. Note that `s(:,1)/norm(s(:,1)) ~= orth(s)(:,1)`

Comment: @ Shai, I think the code works only for square matrices.

Comment: @Heaven why do you think so? `orth` works with non-square matrices as well.

Comment: @Shai a bit late. but i think this solution has a problem. if your random generated matrix `A` were not a full rank matrix then this solution would generate an orthogonal matrix with size differ from m*n. am i right?